# How to show popup window when cookie expires using forms authentication in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to redirect to another page in another application. How to show popup window when cookie expires using forms authentication in asp.net so that before redirect to another page. i.e. In which http: module should I inject logic as cookie is expired and redirect to another application page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not good user interface, and even if you try to make it, every time you going to check if the session is expired, the session will auto renew again, so it not going to work. If the session expired, save the current post data, move it to the login page, let the user login, and then redirect him back where it was. You can how ever make a javascript, just before the user post back to check using ajax, if the session still valid - then show the dialog to login, etc, but even that is hard to made, easy to create bugs and problems with different browser.

Comment: Is there any other way then javascript? Can we not catch the ticket expiry in module event in asp.net application cycle?

Comment: I have changed loginUrl value programmatically, but unable to find its reflection in the application. In application it is using the default value of loginUrl in web.config. Please guide me.